# Worldwide IP Latency

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, network-protocols, icmpv6

I want to create a simulation of the protocol MIPv6 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3775.txt), for this reason I need information about latency, jitter and round-trip time. My first guess is install machines in different parts of the globe and run pings, mtr and  traceroutes, this way I can get some statistics to feed my simulation, I wondering if someone have information about this can share it with me, or can point me to a project/place where I can get this. 
After a google search, I found this http://www.verizonenterprise.com/about/network/latency/, that is too close of what I need.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google term you're looking for is "Looking Glass".  Try Hurricane Electric's, at http://lg.he.net/, to get an idea.